# Regular Expression issue with Fluent validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

Probably very silly issue but looking for help on this .

I am adding MVC Fluent validation rules to model property but for some reason one of the validation rule is failing. Added a regular expression to allow  english and spanish characters and  no numeric or special characters allowed except **- and '**.  For some reason when user enters more than one valid character  as input the error is still displayed.

Error is still displayed when User Input is  **aA**

I am using this RegE **@"^[a-zA-Z-']$")**  to allow users to english and spanish characters and  no numeric or special characters allowed except - and '.

Any help is appreciated.

```
  RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)              
 .NotEmpty().WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_PersonalDetails_1001_firstname)
 .Length(1, 
     20).WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_100006_maxlength) 
 .Matches(@"^[a-zA-Z-']$").WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_Onboarding_PersonalDetails_100007_validname);
```

Comment: `0-9` allows numeric (you said no numeric), but if you want to allow more than one character, `@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-']*$"`

Comment: I think you're just missing a `*` before the `$` (although you're allowing numbers by virtue of having `0-9` in there which you mention you don't want)

Comment: Note also its not necessary to escape the `-` character because its at the end

Comment: @Stephen it's still a good idea to do so since it prevents you from falling in a trap if you add more characters to the group later on without realizing there's a dash at the end (and it's more readable IMO since it stands out).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, Your probably right - just wanted to point it out to OP

Answer (score 10):

Updating the RegE worked - Thankyou all

```
@"^[a-zA-Z-']*$";
```

Comment: Can input remain blank? If so then it is ok, otherwise I would use '+' instead of '*'.

Answer (score 0):

.IsRuleFor(p=>p.yourProperty)
.IsEnglish();

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**